# Office 365 - Save Conflict error when upload sitepage

Tags: office365

I have some site pages aspx.  When I tried to upload file to Site Contents - Site Pages, I got error page popup like that:

"Sorry, something went wrong
Save Conflict

Your changes conflict with those made concurrently by another user. If you want your changes to be applied, click Back in your Web browser, refresh the page, and resubmit your changes."

In my aspx file have Content Editor Web Part. If I delete all html in `<![CDATA[]]>` in node `<Content>` or if I don't delete html I have to set src="" and href="", I can upload aspx file successfully.

Then if my html with src="path" and href="path" I always got Save Conflict error.

What do I need to do ?

[file aspx here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1hw4wESTy9_Znl5N3JmM3ZORUk)

Comment: Some example code if possible please.

Comment: i add a link of file apsx into my post

Comment: somebody can help me, please !